# Can not decide which one suites better for my use case: i5-11600 or i5-11600K?

Tags: cpu, intel-graphics, cpu-cooler

I understand that the main difference between i5-11600 vs i5-11600K is the base frequency: **2.8GHz vs 3.90 GHz**, which will result **TDP 65V vs 125W**. (also there is a minor diff in turbo freq. but that is out of topic)

**Context**

- **My Typical Load:** at 90% of the time I do simple text editing in my developer tools like VS Code, and also browsing, nothing fancy, no games...
- I will use the built in intel graphics 750 in UHD resolution 60Hz.
- (I hope this is out of topic, just for the sake of I am wrong: my planned motherboard is ASUS Prime Z590 )

**My dilemma is the following:**

I would like to my computer as silent as it could be, I mean the CPU cooler should run the lowest speed. Being impatient, at the same time I would not be stuck with the 2.8 GHz with 90% of my time, what is "My Typical Load" with average 10% CPU load...

**Question**

I would pick the i5-11600K with its 3.8GHz base freq, if I could be sure that in "My Typical Load" the CPU cooler will use the same low speed as it would be with i5-11600's 2.8GHz base freq?

Comment: In addition to my answer, I should add that Superuser isn't really the place to ask for hardware recommendations, and you run the risk of your question being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The K variants of Intel CPUs mean that they are unlocked, so you can overclock them if you ever want to.

The TDP in this case is relating to the **maximum** power each chip will use. Out of the box, the 11600 and K variant will use about the same power.

If you are concerned about the noise of a CPU cooler, you might want to look at getting a third party cooler which will be more efficient and will keep the noise a lot lower. There are plenty of comparisons online.

All that being said, your use case of coding and browsing is going to barely tax either of those processors. I assume that if you are using the built in graphics, you aren't going to be doing any indepth machine learning or anything crazy. So in all reality, you are unlikely to see a real difference between them.
The K does give you a little room for future proofing, if you ever want to upgrade your machine further (and looking online, the difference in the UK between the 2 is £10. Get the bigger one ;) )

Comment: Many thx. Do I understand correctly when using approx 10% CPU load, both CPUs power consumption will be so low, so the same cooler will run with the same spee? Btw I will do ML rarely just for the fun, but this case I am going accept that being in turbo the fan will speed up.  In case the CPU not enough I am going to some cloud...